# Class variable Vs. Instance variable in python for int value

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I am new to python and i am not sure how this is working. Code is as below:

```
class test():
    d=0
    def __init__(self):
       self.d=self.d+1;

D=test()
print D.d
D1=test()
print D1.d
D2=test()
print D2.d
```

Output is

```
1,1,1  # This should not be
```

Now using this :

```
class test():
    d=[]
    def __init__(self):
       self.d.apend("1");

 D=test()
 print D.d
 D1=test()
 print D1.d
 D2=test()
 print D2.d
```

Result is (This should be)

```
['1']
['1', '1']
['1', '1', '1']
```

So i am not sure why integer value is not being treated as class variable while list is being treated.

Comment: Why are you using old style classes?

Comment: @spgc I am new, pls tell me new style.

Comment: See my answer. It covers this.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example,

```
self.d = self.d + 1
```

*rebinds* `self.d`, making it independent of `test.d`.

In the second example,

```
   self.d.append("1")
```

*modifies* `test.d`.

To see that for yourself, print `id(self.d)` at the end of both constructors.

If you modified the second example to match the first:

```
   self.d = self.d + ["1"]
```

you'd see that the behaviour would also change to match.

Comment: why it is modifying in second and not in first. I guess it should work same in both case as per operator used.

Comment: @bimleshsharma It's not the same operator. One is assigning, one is not.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, ID is different.

Comment: @bimleshsharma I am not sure what you are trying to tell me with this comment.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify a class variable, do:

```
class test(object):
    d=0
    def __init__(self):
       type(self).d=self.d+1;

D=test()
print D.d
D1=test()
print D1.d
D2=test()
print D2.d
```

You don't need the `type` on the right hand side of the assignment, because this way you never create an instance variable `d`. Note that new-style classes are necessary to this.

`type` is a function (actually a callable - it is also a class; but don't worry about that for now) which returns the class of its argument. So, `type(self)` returns the class of `self`. Classes are first class objects in Python.

Demo here: http://ideone.com/JdNpiV

Update: An alternative would be to use a `classmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

To address a class variable use class_name.variable_name, giving :

```
class test(object):
    d=0
    def __init__(self):
       test.d = test.d + 1;
```

Comment: (a) `x = self.d` will address the class variable `d` if the name is not shadowed by an instance variable (b) this is not the only method of assigning to a class variable (c) this is a bad way of assigning to a class variable, because if the class name changes, you will need to alter all references to the name.

Comment: It is actually wrong in that it falsely implies that `x = self.d` would not work. Your "fix" which you advocate because you did not know that is also bad practice.

Comment: @marcin. Sorry I do not understand your example with x = self.d. Can you update my code to show it?

Comment: What don't you understand? See NPE's answer.

Comment: I understand it is bad coding practice, But I do not understand from your comment why my solution worked and the syntax is allowed?

Comment: Both ways work. One is bad practice. Your answer falsely implies that only one way works. I don't see the confusion here.

Comment: In my opinion : the way Python handles class variables is confusing and the usage is not self explaining. It would be nice to have a alternative for "self", like "cls" in a classmethod, for using a class variable.

Comment: That is the only way to do it in a classmethod. You can call the first argument to a method anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

NPE's answer tells you what is going wrong with your code. However, I'm not sure that it really tells you how to solve the issue properly.

Here's what I think you want, if each `test` instance should have a different `d` value in an instance variable:

```
class test(object): # new style class, since we inherit from "object"
    _d = 0 # this is a class variable, which I've named _d to avoid confusion

    def __init__(self):
        self.d = test._d # assign current value of class variable to an instance variable
        test._d += 1     # increment the class variable
```

Now, you can create multiple instances and each one will get a unique value for `d`:

```
>>> D0 = test()
>>> D1 = test()
>>> D2 = test()
>>> print D0.d
0
>>> print D1.d
1
>>> print D2.d
2
```